# curl: (26) couldn't open file "./Users/name/Desktop/thefile.pdf"

Tags: php, curl, file-upload, terminal, upload

I am supposed to upload a pdf file onto a site using curl on terminal, below is my curl command

```
curl -F file=@/Users/name/Desktop/thespecificfile.pdf http://thewebsite///
```

however i am returned with the text Bad Request
The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

How do i remedy this

i have added a . before /Users/

```
curl -F file=@./Users/name/Desktop/thespecificfile.pdf http://thewebsite///
```

it seems better but this error message pops up

```
curl: (26) couldn't open file "./Users/name/Desktop/thefile.pdf"
```

anyway to remedy this?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need '.' for pdf file url. and don't forget quotes around file.

It should be:

```
curl -F "file=@/Users/name/Desktop/thespecificfile.pdf" "http://thewebsite///"
```